# Как вывести SQLite в ListView

Tags: java, android

Как вывести SQLite в ListView все строки.

```
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ID);
            int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_NAME);
            int emailIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_TEXT);
            int clickIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_TEXT1);
            do {
                String email = cursor.getString(emailIndex);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Он автоматически привязывает данные из курсора к элементам `ListView`.
Создайте SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
String[] from = new String[] {DBHelper.KEY_NAME, DBHelper.KEY_EMAIL, DBHelper.KEY_CLICK};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.click};
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to, 0);
```

Установите адаптер для ListView:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

В разметке `item.xml` вам нужно создать `TextViews` с соответствующими идентификаторами `R.id.name, R.id.email и R.id.click`, в которые будут загружаться данные из курсора.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает